# Laravel 8 update product in cart if exists

Tags: php, laravel, cart, shopping-cart

I'm using a Laravel 8 with **darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart** Cart Package. I'm struggling a bit with updating product quantity if it exists in users cart.
For example: If cart is empty, while adding a product and then clicking mutliple times on "Add To Cart" it adds only one product and then updates quantity to its maximum. But when I'm adding a second product, and then adding again product 1 it adds another product to the cart. It definitely should not add another product but it has to be restricted to maximum quantity of first product.

My cart store method:

```
    public function store(CartStoreRequest $request) {

        $validated = $request->validated();
        $product = Product::findOrFail($validated['product_id']);

        $rowId = uniqid();
        $userID = $validated['user_id'];

        // get current user cart
        $currentCart = \Cart::session($userID);

        if(!empty($currentCart->getContent()->toArray())) {
            foreach($currentCart->getContent() as $item) {
                $productID = $item->associatedModel->id;

                if($productID === $product->id) {
                    $currentCart->update($item->id, [
                        'quantity' => [
                         'relative' => false,
                         'value' => $product->minStock($item->quantity + $validated['quantity']),
                        ]
                    ]);
                } else {
                    $currentCart->add(array(
                        'id' => $rowId,
                        'name' => $product->name,
                        'price' => $product->price->amount(),
                        'quantity' => $validated['quantity'],
                        'associatedModel' => $product,
                        'attributes' => array(
                            'first_image' => $product->firstImage,
                            'formatted_price' => $product->formattedPrice,
                            'product_stock' => $product->stockCount()
                        )
                    ));
                }
            }
        } else {
            $currentCart->add(array(
                'id' => $rowId,
                'name' => $product->name,
                'price' => $product->price->amount(),
                'quantity' => $validated['quantity'],
                'associatedModel' => $product,
                'attributes' => array(
                    'first_image' => $product->firstImage,
                    'formatted_price' => $product->formattedPrice,
                    'product_stock' => $product->stockCount()
                )
            ));
        }

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

I hope that's someone had similar problem and knows how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the solution is to use product ID as $rowId,

```
        $validated = $request->validated();
        $product = Product::findOrFail($validated['product_id']);

        $rowId = $product->id;
        $userID = $validated['user_id'];
        $currentCart = \Cart::session($userID);

        $currentCart->add(array(
            'id' => $rowId,
            'name' => $product->name,
            'price' => $product->price->amount(),
            'quantity' => $product->minStock($validated['quantity']),
            'associatedModel' => $product,
            'attributes' => array(
                'first_image' => $product->firstImage,
                'formatted_price' => $product->formattedPrice,
                'product_stock' => $product->stockCount()
            )
        ));

        $currentCartContents = $currentCart->get($rowId);
        $quantity = $product->minStock($currentCartContents->quantity);

        if($currentCartContents->quantity !== $quantity) {
            $currentCart->update($rowId, [
                'quantity' => [
                 'relative' => false,
                 'value' => $quantity,
                ]
            ]);
        }

        return redirect()->back();
```